# Sample default WebGL color buffer

Tags: javascript, webgl

Is it possible to sample the default color buffer like a texture?

I would like to do something like this:

1. Render a cube
2. Render a fullscreen quad that blurs the cube

The reason that I don't want to render to a framebuffer is that WebGL has multisampling when using the default color buffer but not for framebuffers. A good solution would be to render to the default buffer and then copy it to a framebuffer or texture, but I'm not sure if/how that is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly sample from the default color buffer, however the default *framebuffer* it's attached to is exactly that, a *framebuffer* and you can call `copyTexImage2D` on it and have the contents copied to the currently bound and active texture.

```
// initializing the texture
const targetTexture = gl.createTexture();
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, targetTexture);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

// in your render loop
gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null);
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, targetTexture);
gl.copyTexImage2D(
    gl.TEXTURE_2D, //target
    0, // mip level, has to be zero for default framebuffer
    gl.RGBA, // pixel format, default framebuffer is RGBA if the context was created with alpha false you need to use RGB
    0, 0, // x,y
    gl.drawingBufferWidth, // width
    gl.drawingBufferHeight, // height
    0 // border, always 0
);
```

```js
// WebGL - Copy Default Framebuffer
// from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55228453/sample-default-webgl-color-buffer/
// based on https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/webgl-render-to-texture.html

"use strict";

function main() {
  // Get A WebGL context
  /** @type {HTMLCanvasElement} */
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");
  if (!gl) {
    return;
  }

  // setup GLSL program
  var program = webglUtils.createProgramFromScripts(gl, ["3d-vertex-shader", "3d-fragment-shader"]);

  // look up where the vertex data needs to go.
  var positionLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "a_position");
  var texcoordLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "a_texcoord");

  // lookup uniforms
  var matrixLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_matrix");
  var textureLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_texture");

  // Create a buffer for positions
  var positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  // Bind it to ARRAY_BUFFER (think of it as ARRAY_BUFFER = positionBuffer)
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
  // Put the positions in the buffer
  setGeometry(gl);

  // provide texture coordinates for the rectangle.
  var texcoordBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, texcoordBuffer);
  // Set Texcoords.
  setTexcoords(gl);

  // Create a texture.
  var texture = gl.createTexture();
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);

  {
    // fill texture with 3x2 pixels
    const level = 0;
    const internalFormat = gl.LUMINANCE;
    const width = 3;
    const height = 2;
    const border = 0;
    const format = gl.LUMINANCE;
    const type = gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE;
    const data = new Uint8Array([
      128,  64, 128,
        0, 192,   0,
    ]);
    const alignment = 1;
    gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, alignment);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, level, internalFormat, width, height, border,
                  format, type, data);

    // set the filtering so we don't need mips and it's not filtered
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  }

  // Create a texture to render to
  const targetTextureWidth = gl.drawingBufferWidth;
  const targetTextureHeight = gl.drawingBufferHeight;
  const targetTexture = gl.createTexture();
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, targetTexture);

  {
    // define size and format of level 0
    const level = 0;
    const internalFormat = gl.RGBA;
    const border = 0;
    const format = gl.RGBA;
    const type = gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE;
    const data = null;
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, level, internalFormat,
                  targetTextureWidth, targetTextureHeight, border,
                  format, type, data);

    // set the filtering so we don't need mips
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  }

  function degToRad(d) {
    return d * Math.PI / 180;
  }

  var fieldOfViewRadians = degToRad(60);
  var modelXRotationRadians = degToRad(0);
  var modelYRotationRadians = degToRad(0);

  // Get the starting time.
  var then = 0;

  requestAnimationFrame(drawScene);

  function drawCube(aspect) {
    // Tell it to use our program (pair of shaders)
    gl.useProgram(program);

    // Turn on the position attribute
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionLocation);

    // Bind the position buffer.
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);

    // Tell the position attribute how to get data out of positionBuffer (ARRAY_BUFFER)
    var size = 3;          // 3 components per iteration
    var type = gl.FLOAT;   // the data is 32bit floats
    var normalize = false; // don't normalize the data
    var stride = 0;        // 0 = move forward size * sizeof(type) each iteration to get the next position
    var offset = 0;        // start at the beginning of the buffer
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(
        positionLocation, size, type, normalize, stride, offset);

    // Turn on the teccord attribute
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(texcoordLocation);

    // Bind the position buffer.
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, texcoordBuffer);

    // Tell the position attribute how to get data out of positionBuffer (ARRAY_BUFFER)
    var size = 2;          // 2 components per iteration
    var type = gl.FLOAT;   // the data is 32bit floats
    var normalize = false; // don't normalize the data
    var stride = 0;        // 0 = move forward size * sizeof(type) each iteration to get the next position
    var offset = 0;        // start at the beginning of the buffer
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(
        texcoordLocation, size, type, normalize, stride, offset);

    // Compute the projection matrix
    var projectionMatrix =
        m4.perspective(fieldOfViewRadians, aspect, 1, 2000);

    var cameraPosition = [0, 0, 2];
    var up = [0, 1, 0];
    var target = [0, 0, 0];

    // Compute the camera's matrix using look at.
    var cameraMatrix = m4.lookAt(cameraPosition, target, up);

    // Make a view matrix from the camera matrix.
    var viewMatrix = m4.inverse(cameraMatrix);

    var viewProjectionMatrix = m4.multiply(projectionMatrix, viewMatrix);

    var matrix = m4.xRotate(viewProjectionMatrix, modelXRotationRadians);
    matrix = m4.yRotate(matrix, modelYRotationRadians);

    // Set the matrix.
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(matrixLocation, false, matrix);

    // Tell the shader to use texture unit 0 for u_texture
    gl.uniform1i(textureLocation, 0);

    // Draw the geometry.
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6 * 6);
  }

  // Draw the scene.
  function drawScene(time) {
    // convert to seconds
    time *= 0.001;
    // Subtract the previous time from the current time
    var deltaTime = time - then;
    // Remember the current time for the next frame.
    then = time;

    // Animate the rotation
    modelYRotationRadians += -0.7 * deltaTime;
    modelXRotationRadians += -0.4 * deltaTime;

    webglUtils.resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(gl.canvas);

    gl.enable(gl.CULL_FACE);
    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);

    {
      // render cube with our 3x2 texture
      gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);

      // Tell WebGL how to convert from clip space to pixels
      gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);

      // Clear the canvas AND the depth buffer.
      gl.clearColor(0, 0, 1, 1);   // clear to blue
      gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

      const aspect = targetTextureWidth / targetTextureHeight;
      drawCube(aspect);
    }

    {
      // render the cube with the texture we just rendered to
      gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, targetTexture);      
      gl.copyTexImage2D(
         gl.TEXTURE_2D, //target
          0, // mip level, has to be zero for default framebuffer
          gl.RGBA, // pixel format, default framebuffer is RGBA
          0, 0, // x,y
          gl.drawingBufferWidth, // width
          gl.drawingBufferHeight, // height
          0 // border, always 0
      );

      // Tell WebGL how to convert from clip space to pixels
      gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);

      // Clear the canvas AND the depth buffer.
      gl.clearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);   // clear to white
      gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);


      const aspect = gl.canvas.clientWidth / gl.canvas.clientHeight;
      drawCube(aspect);
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(drawScene);
  }
}

// Fill the buffer with the values that define a cube.
function setGeometry(gl) {
  var positions = new Float32Array(
    [
    -0.5, -0.5,  -0.5,
    -0.5,  0.5,  -0.5,
     0.5, -0.5,  -0.5,
    -0.5,  0.5,  -0.5,
     0.5,  0.5,  -0.5,
     0.5, -0.5,  -0.5,

    -0.5, -0.5,   0.5,
     0.5, -0.5,   0.5,
    -0.5,  0.5,   0.5,
    -0.5,  0.5,   0.5,
     0.5, -0.5,   0.5,
     0.5,  0.5,   0.5,

    -0.5,   0.5, -0.5,
    -0.5,   0.5,  0.5,
     0.5,   0.5, -0.5,
    -0.5,   0.5,  0.5,
     0.5,   0.5,  0.5,
     0.5,   0.5, -0.5,

    -0.5,  -0.5, -0.5,
     0.5,  -0.5, -0.5,
    -0.5,  -0.5,  0.5,
    -0.5,  -0.5,  0.5,
     0.5,  -0.5, -0.5,
     0.5,  -0.5,  0.5,

    -0.5,  -0.5, -0.5,
    -0.5,  -0.5,  0.5,
    -0.5,   0.5, -0.5,
    -0.5,  -0.5,  0.5,
    -0.5,   0.5,  0.5,
    -0.5,   0.5, -0.5,

     0.5,  -0.5, -0.5,
     0.5,   0.5, -0.5,
     0.5,  -0.5,  0.5,
     0.5,  -0.5,  0.5,
     0.5,   0.5, -0.5,
     0.5,   0.5,  0.5,

    ]);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positions, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
}

// Fill the buffer with texture coordinates the cube.
function setTexcoords(gl) {
  gl.bufferData(
      gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,
      new Float32Array(
        [
          0, 0,
          0, 1,
          1, 0,
          0, 1,
          1, 1,
          1, 0,

          0, 0,
          0, 1,
          1, 0,
          1, 0,
          0, 1,
          1, 1,

          0, 0,
          0, 1,
          1, 0,
          0, 1,
          1, 1,
          1, 0,

          0, 0,
          0, 1,
          1, 0,
          1, 0,
          0, 1,
          1, 1,

          0, 0,
          0, 1,
          1, 0,
          0, 1,
          1, 1,
          1, 0,

          0, 0,
          0, 1,
          1, 0,
          1, 0,
          0, 1,
          1, 1,

      ]),
      gl.STATIC_DRAW);
}

main();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" style="width:512px;height:512px"></canvas>

<!-- vertex shader -->
<script id="3d-vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
attribute vec4 a_position;
attribute vec2 a_texcoord;

uniform mat4 u_matrix;

varying vec2 v_texcoord;

void main() {
  // Multiply the position by the matrix.
  gl_Position = u_matrix * a_position;

  // Pass the texcoord to the fragment shader.
  v_texcoord = a_texcoord;
}
</script>
<!-- fragment shader -->
<script id="3d-fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
precision mediump float;

// Passed in from the vertex shader.
varying vec2 v_texcoord;

// The texture.
uniform sampler2D u_texture;

void main() {
   gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_texture, v_texcoord);
}
</script>
<!--
for most samples webgl-utils only provides shader compiling/linking and
canvas resizing because why clutter the examples with code that's the same in every sample.
See http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-boilerplate.html
and http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-resizing-the-canvas.html
for webgl-utils, m3, m4, and webgl-lessons-ui.
-->
<script src="https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/resources/webgl-utils.js"></script>
<script src="https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/resources/m4.js"></script>
```

Comment: I can't get it to work. I get this error: `ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glCopyTexImage2D: incompatible format` The internalformat of the target texture is `RGBA`.

Comment: The reason I got this error was because I created the `WebGLRenderingContext` with the `{ "alpha": false }` option. Instead of doing that, I set the alpha channel to 1 after rendering as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39341564/webgl-how-to-correctly-blend-alpha-channel-png/39354174#39354174) and it works. Thank you!