# background-color vs COLOR_BUFFER_BIT

Tags: webgl

If I put a clearcolor with zero alpha, I don't understand why we then see the color given in CSS of the canvas rather than the CSS color of the body. On canvas, what is the difference between WebGLRenderingContext.clearColor() and background-color?

```js
const gl = document.getElementById("c").getContext("webgl", {
  premultipliedAlpha: false,
});
gl.clearColor(0, 1, 0, 0);
gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```

```css
canvas {
  background-color: rgba(255,0,0,1);
 
}
body {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,255,1);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

i found !

> [WebGL: How to correctly blend alpha channel png](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39341564/webgl-how-to-correctly-blend-alpha-channel-png)
>
> > Do you or do you not want your WebGL image blended with the webpage?
> > If no, you don't want to blend with the webpage then do one of the
> > following :
> >
> > - turn off alpha in the canvas  var gl = someCanvas.getContext("webgl", { alpha: false });

```js
const gl = document.getElementById("c").getContext("webgl", {
  premultipliedAlpha: false,
  alpha:false
});
gl.clearColor(0, 1, 0, 0);
gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```

```css
canvas {
  background-color: rgba(255,0,0,1);
 
}
body {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,255,1);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```